# Swift 4 - PDFAnnotation text (or UITextField) to be the size of the text

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a PDFAnnotation Text Widget and everything is working great, its multiline, so what I am trying to do set the size of this Annotation to be the size of text...does this make sense? How would I do that?

Here is my Annotation:

```
let page = pdfView.currentPage

            textAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: CGRect(x: 300, y: 200, width: 600, height: 100), forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget.rawValue), withProperties: nil)

            textAnnotation.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.text.rawValue)

            textAnnotation.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80)

            textAnnotation.fontColor = .red

            textAnnotation.isMultiline = true

            textAnnotation.widgetStringValue = "Text Here"

            page!.addAnnotation(textAnnotation)
```

How do I make the size of the text like in the native tool? Or how I do this to a UITextField because I can probably do more or less the same thing.

Still got nothing on this....its super hard.

**UPDATE**

Still have made no process on this. But after reviewing the native iOS PDF Annotations, it appears it does not make the text field long in width, but goes to the next line and makes the height of the text area bigger....I have my PDFAnnotation set to isMultiline, but when I goto the next line I can't see it because my height is only 100.0....So How would it make goto the next line and increase the height of the text area?

**UPDATE**

I created my own custom PDFAnnotation

```
class TextAnnotation:  PDFAnnotation {

    var currentText: String?

    override init(bounds: CGRect, forType annotationType: PDFAnnotationSubtype, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: annotationType, withProperties: properties)

        self.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.text.rawValue)

        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80)

        self.isMultiline = true

        self.widgetStringValue = "Text Here"

        self.currentText = self.widgetStringValue!
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.saveGState()

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
        ]

        widgetStringValue!.draw(in: pageBounds, withAttributes: attributes)

        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I noticed that the draw method gets called every time I type something, so what I tried to do is compare self.widgetStringValue against the variable currentText but when I try to changed the width if they do no equal each other, it doesn't do anything.

Maybe I can create a delegate method and call it in my ViewController to remove / add the Annotation again...or try to change the bounds from there.

Comment: I'm not expert in PDFKit so I will ask about UITextField: what exactly do you want in case of UITextField? You have text message and you want your UITextField to be exact size to fit the message. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I want the PDFAnnotation Widget of Text to fit the message while I am trying or going to a new line.

Comment: What is the purpose of the widget as it relates to your app?  It would be really helpful to have some screenshots/video of the behavior your want/expect VS the behavior you are getting that you don't want.

Comment: The purpose of the text widget is to add text to the PDF and let the user edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the height by using a simple helper function as such

```
/*
- Parameters:
   - constrainedWidth: The max width of the label
   - fontSize: Font size used for the UILabel
   - text: The String used in the calculations

- Returns: CGFLoat which is the height of the label
*/
func estimatedHeight(constrainedWidth width: CGFloat, fontSize: CGFloat, text:String) -> CGFloat {
    let tempLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    tempLabel.text = text
    tempLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    tempLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    tempLabel.font.withSize(fontSize)
    tempLabel.sizeToFit()

    return tempLabel.frame.height
}
```

from that function you will receive the height for the UILabel, you could then simply add any padding or margins to your annotations height that it needs.

Comment: I dont think this will work for the PDFAnnotation widget text.

Comment: Like I starting to think now I can't access the UITextField inside the annotation

Comment: Why can’t you access it? I changed nothing about your code instead I gave you a method of getting just the estimated height back for the text. Don’t use a UILabel, I just used that for an estimate of the height of the container based on the width you want for the text